# error parsing manifest

Tags: ros, package, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I was following the tutorial "creating a ROS package by hand".

In my catkin_ws/src I created a folder  mpc_wheelchair_pkg and I put a manifest there called "package.xml" and edited it like this

```
<package>

<name>mpc_wheelchair</name>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<description>blabla</description>
<mainteiner email="blabla@blabla">blabla</maintainer>
<license>BSD</license>

<buildtool_depend>catkin</buoldtool_depend>

<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<build_depend>std_msg</build_depend>

<run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
<run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>

</package>
```

then I tried to use rospack as the tutorial suggested and this happened

```
viki@c3po:~$ rospack find mpc_wheelchair
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rospack::Exception'
      what():  error parsing manifest of package mpc_wheelchair_pkg at /home/viki/catkin_ws/src/mpc_wheelchair_pkg/package.xml
    Aborted
```

moreover if I now try "rospack find" with something else I always get the same exception

```
viki@c3po:~$ rospack find beginner_tutorials
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rospack::Exception'
  what():  error parsing manifest of package mpc_wheelchair_pkg at /home/viki/catkin_ws/src/mpc_wheelchair_pkg/package.xml
Aborted
```

Does someone know what I should do?
I use ROS indigo on a virtualboxed ubuntu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201409/error-parsing-manifest/) by [carrello](https://answers.ros.org/users/20713/carrello/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you have an error in this line, where you wrote buoldtool instead of buildtool:

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buoldtool_depend>
```

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [carrello](https://answers.ros.org/users/20713/carrello/) on 2015-01-21**:
thank you :)